# Using key name to index json object gives error [[keyname]] can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rest

I'm fetching news from a news api with sample response as below. When i try to accesses the articles the line data['articles'] generates following error-

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"articles"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
Property 'articles' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 11814,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": "engadget",
"name": "Engadget"
},
"author": "https://www.engadget.com/about/editors/richard-lawler",
"title": "Tesla 'suspends' Bitcoin car purchases citing environmental impact",
"description": "You can't buy a Tesla with Bitcoin anymore..",
"url": "https://www.engadget.com/elon-musk-bitcoin-221708146.html",
"urlToImage": "https://s.yimg.com/os/creatr-uploaded-images/2021-05/a0f90c30-b36f-11eb-aff6-04fb28cf2f4b",
"publishedAt": "2021-05-12T22:17:08Z",
"content": "Just weeks after Tesla started accepting Bitcoin as currency for cars, Elon Musk revealed in a tweet that it will \"suspend\" the effort. According to the release (Tesla does not appear to have a funct… [+768 chars]"
},......
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsApiService {

  apiKey='f635258abaf9455c876874a78a5ca745';
  url='https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=trading&'+'apiKey=f635258abaf9455c876874a78a5ca745';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  public getNews()
  {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{NewsApiService} from 'src/app/services/news-api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-newsfeed',
  templateUrl: './newsfeed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newsfeed.component.css']
})
export class NewsfeedComponent implements OnInit {

  articlelist:any;
  constructor(private apiService:NewsApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.apiService.getNews().subscribe((data)=>{console.log(data);
    this.articlelist=data['articles']})

    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http.get is by default returning an `Object` type. You should typecast it. For now `any` would work but I suggest creating an interface specific for your type:

```js
  public getNews()
  {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
  }
```

**(Optional)**
Depending on how strict your typescript configuration is you might need to add it to your callback as well:

```js
this.apiService.getNews().subscribe((data: any)=>{console.log(data);
```